# Capture all click event and retrieve id and text of clicked view

Tags: android, touch, multi-touch

I want to write a method so if called this method in my activity , It should do the below two things

1)   it should track all the touch and click events of user

2)   It should fetch the id and text of the view which user have clicked or touched

3) I don't want to use custom view. I want to write a general method.

Is there any way to achieve this ? If yes please enlighten me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution here would first be to create your own custom views like TextView, ImageView and whatever you want, then override the touch methods and then call your Activity through a listener to notify the event.

Hope that helps, greetings.

Comment: No no not this. Suppose I have given that method to you. and you have called the method in your Activity and you are not using custom views then how to do that . I want to make it independent.